# Критерії оцінювання швидкості читання? / Reading speed norms?

Tags: language-regulation, вивчення-мови

Якими є офіційні критерії оцінювання **швидкості читання/розуміння текстів** для випускників навчальних закладів?

Спробував поґуґлити і нічого не знайшов — цілком припускаю, що сайти Міносвіти забороняють індексацію чи абощо.

Найбільше цікавлять дві категорії:

1. Випускники загальноосвітніх шкіл;
2. Випускники вишів.

Неофіційні джерела вказують 90-95 слів/хв. для читання вголос і 100-170 слів/хв. для читання мовчки. Але не прив'язують ці числа до категорій учнів. Окрім того, 100-170 — це дуже великий розброс значень.

Будь ласка, у відповідях надавайте пряме посилання на відповідні вказівки Міносвіти та/або Закони України.

---

What are the officially adopted norms for **reading and comprehension** for graduates of Ukrainian schools?

Tried to search the sites of Ministry of Education of Ukraine with no result.

Most of all, I'd like to know these norms for two categories of graduates:

1. Graduates of regular high schools;
2. Graduates of higher schools/universities.

Unofficial sources cite 90-95 words/minute for reading aloud and 100-170 words/minute for silent reading. But they do not associate the numbers with different student/graduate categories. Also, 100…170 seems to be a too wide range.

Please provide references to Ministry of Education and/or Laws of Ukraine.

Comment: Не думаю що для випускників вишів є якісь критерії по читанню. З мого досвіду, швидкість читання контролюєтся лише у початковій школі. Був дуже вражений, коли виявилося що у 10 классі одна з моїх однокласниць мала великі проблеми із читанням вголос (зрозуміло що вона була "трієчницею", але такого рівня я не очікував).

Comment: @Artemix, я взагалі здивований, що такі критерії не прописані для **кожного** класу школи. Причому у вигляді таблиці виду «швидкість-оцінка».

Comment: @Artemix, підтримую. В старших класах і вишах напевно **інші** критерії успішності. Оцінювати швидкість читання в старших класах/вишах якось безглуздо, там оцінюють вже більш серйозні навички. А для молодших класів читання на швидкість нещодавно [відмінили](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/society/2016/08/160804_elementary_education_dk).

Comment: @bytebuster, а як були особам з дефектами (дислексія тощо) — не випускати їх зі школи? (По-моєму, в середніх/старших класах і не повинно бути таких примітивних вимірювань — має оцінюватись здатність учня виконувати складні завдання в цілому, а не «як швидко читає», «як швидко рахує», «як ретельно пише». А от чи правильно, що відмінили таке в молодших класах — питання дискусійне.)

Comment: Друзі, @Sasha, ну при чому тут дислексія?! Йдеться про регулярні загальноосвітні державні заклади. Перепрошую, але давайте не займатися [cherry-picking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Faulty_generalizations). Якщо таких критеріїв нема (and you have reasons to think so) — це буде правильною відповіддю на запитання.

Comment: Критерії оцінювання навчальних досягнень учнів 5-11 класів з української мови та української літератури. Швидкість читання мовчки (слів за хвилину): 12-й клас - 170 – 360 http://blolena.blogspot.com/2014/12/5-11.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На сайті МОН є такий документ ([пдф](http://mon.gov.ua/content/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0/ukr-mova-(1).pdf)), але не зрозуміло його статус і яка саме сторінка сайту веде на цей документ. Схоже що це методичні вказівки.

Ось його початок:

> ## Українська мова
>
> У 2012-2013 навчальному році вивчення української мови у 5-9 класах
> загальноосвітніх навчальних закладів здійснюватиметься за програмою,
> затвердженою Міністерством освіти і науки України (лист №1/11-6611 від
> 23.12.2004 року): Українська мова. 5-12 класи /Автори Г.Т. Шелехова,
> В.І. Тихоша, А.М. Корольчук, В.І. Новосьолова, Я.І. Остаф. За редакцією
> Л.В. Скуратівського. – К.: Ірпінь: Перун, 2005. – 176 с.

У цьому документі є розділ "читання мовчки" з такою таблицею:

```
Клас    Швидкість читання мовчки (слів за хвилину)
5-й     100 – 150
6-й     110 – 180
7-й     120 – 210
8-й     130 – 240
9-й     140 – 270
10-й    150 – 300
11-й    160 – 330
```

Схожа таблиця є у "Програма з української мови для учнів 5-12 класів (для шкіл з українською мовою навчання)" із рядком для 12 класу. Цю програму можна знайти за [цим посиланням](http://iteach.com.ua/resources/full-time-tuition/m1/vp6/school/) (не на сайті МОН).

```
12-й    170 – 360
```

<s>Думаю що на сайті МОН мені не вдалося знайти подібних таблиць оскільки...</s>

#### UPD

У новій програмі такі критерії є, просто вони не зведені у одну таблицю, а розбиті по окремих документах.

Програма ["Українська мова - академічний рівень"](http://mon.gov.ua/content/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0/ukr-m-ak.pdf) вказує для 11 класу такі вимоги:

```
Клас     Швидкість читання мовчки (слів за хвилину)
10-й     150 – 300
11-й     160 – 330
```

Посилання на документ на сайті МОН розміщено на сторінці [Навчальні програми](http://mon.gov.ua/activity/education/zagalna-serednya/navchalni-programy.html) у таблиці "Навчальні програми для 10-11 класів загальноосвітніх навчальних закладів", рядок "Українська мова" - "академічний рівень".

Comment: Вточнення: я казав, що відмінено читання на швидкість в *початкових* класах (та й про те не впевнений на 100% — це просто з новин, а не з досвіду).

Comment: @Sasha, так, вимоги щодо швидкості читання є у програмі для 10-11 класів - виправив відповідь.